# What's the MvcHtmlString DialogFormLink callback?

Tags: html, razor

In a old page of a C# MVC ASP .NET site there are some links built with MvcHtmlString DialogFormLink, and these links opens a little popup page asking simple data to the user.
These pages have two buttons, save and cancel.
I need to do something on the page (not on the popup), changing colors and texts, after the user clicks on the "save" button, and I can't do nothing when the user clicks on the "cancel" button.

Someone can tell me what is the last parameter, the "callback"?
This call expects a string, what is this string? a URL (something in my controller), a Javascript? Anything else?

```
MvcHtmlString DialogFormLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string dialogContentUrl, string dialogId, string dialogTitle, string updateTargetId, string updateUrl, string callback = null)
```

Comment: What is `DialogFormLink()`? That is not part of MVC or the `HtmlHelper` class, and is obviously a custom extension method

Comment: You're right ... looking better this is something found somewhere from the person who wrote the site, and extended without any documentation ...

Comment: The name of the argument suggests its might be for the name of a javascript function that will be called (similar to the `OnBegin` ajax option in `Ajax.ActionLink()`)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you: by try and error i found a the callback function must be a Javascript function, with no parameters or a boolean parameter.